# Keep column names while reading pandas dataframe with nrows and skiprows

Tags: python, pandas

I am reading a big datafile by defining the number of rows to read and the number of rows to skip using the variable `nbr_rows_to_read` and `nbr_rows_to_skip`

```
data_df = pd.read_csv(data_file, delimiter="|", nrows=nbr_rows_to_read,
                      skiprows=nbr_rows_to_skip, 
                      dtype={'col1':object,'col2':object,'col3':object, 'col4': object})
```

The problem is that, the column names are only read in the first chunk that skips 0 rows. For other chunks, I get the first row of the values defined as the column names. How can I keep the column names in the other chunks?

Comment: @jezrael, instead of using chunksize I am limiting the chunk size by defining the  number of rows to read and skip.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC you can use `list` of numbers instead on `integer` in parameter `skiprows` of [`read_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html):

> skiprows : list-like or integer, default None
>
> Line numbers to skip (0-indexed) or number of lines to skip (int) at the start of the file

Demo:

```
import pandas as pd
import io

#test data
temp=u"""id|col1|col2|col3
1|13|15|0
1|13|15|1
1|13|15|2
1|12|15|3
1|13|15|4
1|12|15|5
1|12|15|6
2|18|15|7"""


#skip first data rows, keep header
nbr_rows_to_skip = range(1, 2)
nbr_rows_to_read = 6 

data_df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(temp), delimiter="|", nrows=nbr_rows_to_read, skiprows=nbr_rows_to_skip, dtype={'col1':object,'col2':object,'col3':object, 'col4': object})
print data_df
#   id col1 col2 col3
#0   1   13   15    1
#1   1   13   15    2
#2   1   12   15    3
#3   1   13   15    4
#4   1   12   15    5
#5   1   12   15    6
```